# In Anypoint Studio 7, Is there any way to setup an audio cue when my build is done?

Tags: mulesoft, anypoint-studio

I am looking for a way to set up an audio cue when my Anypoint Studio 7 is done building a project, as I am just fed up with having to wait so long for a build, I want to do something else during the build but also want to work efficiently by returning back to work as soon as the build is done. I have found this interesting page how to set it up on Eclipse:
https://mcuoneclipse.com/2021/04/20/play-a-sound-at-the-end-of-the-build-with-eclipse/

Since Studio is based on Eclipse, I thought I could set it up the same way, but I cant find the Post-Build steps shown on the page. Is there any way I can access those steps or is there maybe another way to setup an audio cue?

Answer (score 1):

The article you shared showed a feature specific of the [Eclipse C/C++ Development Tools](https://github.com/eclipse-cdt) plugin, which only builds C/C++ projects. There is not a similar feature for Java projects nor Anypoint Studio projects.

While I would not recommend it, an alternative could be to create a command line (.bat/.ps in Windows)/shell script (.sh for other platforms) that would execute Maven (passing the same arguments) and then execute a beep command. In Anypoint Studio preferences you can change the command used to execute Maven, which is called `mvn` by default. It should be possible to add your custom script in the same MAVEN_HOME/bin directory.

I strongly advice against modifying the scripts from the Maven distribution. That is a bad practice and could cause confusions if not breakings with updates.

Answer (score 0):

I found somewhat of a solution.

There is a maven plugin exec-maven-plugin that allows for running applications at certain stages of the build lifecycle. You add this in the pom.xml inside the plugins tag:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>${basedir}/Beep.bat</executable>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

This will run the file.bat in the root of the project, same level as the pom.xml, as soon as the build enters the 'package' lifecycle. In my question there is a link that mentions how to make such a .bat file.

The problem with this method is that it looks at the maven lifecycle, and not the Anypoint Studio one. I want the file to be executed as soon as the console informs me that the deployment was successful, but it seems that it is not the 'deploy' lifecycle.

I just want an audio cue as soon as I can send a Postman request aka get to this console message:
[image: status deployed]